# foreach in blade template not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having issues on displaying my data from foreach loop. I have 400+ thumbs on my database but laravel doesn't not work correctly, and my footer template didn't display too. I will put my code below.

```
@foreach($thumbs as $thumb)
   {{$thumb['name']}}
   {{$thumb['desc']}}
   {{$thumb['place']}}
@endforeach

myfooter code goes here.
```

from my controllers

```
$data['thumbs'] = thumb::all();
return View('tubetour/home',$data);
```

but when I tried to var_dump or return the value of thumbs on my controller
it displays all my 400+ data.

```
$data['thumbs'] = thumb::all();
return $data['thumbs'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Thumb` is an Eloquent model, then the `Thumb::all()` will return an Eloquent collection, not an array. In that case you have to update your blade template like so:

```
@foreach($thumbs as $thumb)
    {{ $thumb->name }}
    {{ $thumb->desc }}
    {{ $thumb->place }}
@endforeach
```

Hope this solve your issue.

**UPDATE**

Pass the `$thumbs` as an array and display it as table.

Update your controller like this:

```
$data['thumbs'] = thumb::all()->toArray();
return View('tubetour/home', $data);
```

And your view like this, see how many rows being displayed.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>Id</tr>
        <tr>Name</tr>
        <td>Desc</td>
        <td>Place</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for ($i = 0; $i < count($thumbs); $i++)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                <td>{{ $thumbs[$i]['name'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $thumbs[$i]['desc'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $thumbs[$i]['place'] }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endfor
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Blade template example with bootstrap grid:

```
<div class="row">
    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($thumbs); $i++)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/sample.jpg">
            <h3>{{ $thumbs[$i]['name'] }}</h3>
            {{ $thumbs[$i]['desc'] }}
        </div>
    @endfor
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this also but no luck. it only display 50 or 60 or random number of thumbs but not displaying the correct 400+ thumbs

Comment: im wondering if this is the foreach issue on laravel blade template?

Comment: On your blade template, add:

 `<h1>TOTAL: {{ count($thumb) }}</h1>`

to see how many records being passed to the view. What's the total being displayed?

Comment: it says 431 thumbs

Comment: im suspecting that too much code in foreach leads the laravel blade not to display all the thumbs i have.

Comment: maybe i will try the <?php ?> tag and see how it works.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet, let's try to display all `thumbs` on a table. See how many rows being displayed. There's a probability that some of your records are empty.

Comment: it worked! it displays all. but when i tried to add a bootstrap code like `<div class="col-md-4"><img src="img/sample.jpg">$thumbs[$i]['name']<br>$thumbs[$i]['desc']</div>` all thumb doesnt work again.

Comment: Just add an example of using bootstrap grid. Does it work?

Comment: yeah it doesn't work. i tried also to code just a simple div element like `<div></div>` all data wont display again.

Comment: @RisanBagjaPradana, kindly check my answer below.

Comment: hey guys i knew the answer right now. it was output buffer. the php limits the display on the foreach.

Comment: thanks on the effort you helping me. thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an associative array as a second argument to the `view` function:

```
// Controller
$thumbs = Thumb::all();
return \View::make('tubetour.home', ['thumbs' => $thumbs]);

// View
@foreach($thumbs as $thumb)
    {{ $thumb->name }}
    {{ $thumb->desc }}
    {{ $thumb->place }}
@endforeach
```

Edit: if you are using laravel 4 you will need to use `View::make()`

Comment: I tried what you posted here. but still no luck. i doesn't display all 400+ thumbs. Im suspecting if this is a laravel issue?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
@foreach($data as $thumb)
   {{$thumb['name']}}
   {{$thumb['desc']}}
   {{$thumb['place']}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller

```
$data = Thumb::all();
return View::make('tubetour/home')->with("thumbs",$data)
                                  ->render();
```

Then your view with this:

```
@foreach($thumbs as $thumb)
   {{$thumb['name']}}
   {{$thumb['desc']}}
   {{$thumb['place']}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your code actually does exactly the same as his behind the scenes, this won't really change anything